# Capturing Holiday when computing 3 business days prior from given date

Tags: python

Lets say we have a date as `2019-11-19` which is Tuesday. Now I want to get the 3 business days back from Tuesday i.e. I want to get `2019-11-15` as 16th and 17th are Saturday and Sunday respectively. To achieve this I have the following code:

```
dt_tue = datetime.strptime('2019-11-19','%Y-%m-%d')
bd-3 = dt_tue - timedelta(days=3)    #<--- 3 business days prior
for i in range(bd_3.day,dt_tue.day+1):
  dt_in = datetime(dt_tue.year,dt_tue.month,i)
  if dt_in.weekday() > 5:
    bd_3 = dt_tue - timedelta(4)
```

The above code generates bd_3 as 15th Nov 2019 which is Friday, and this is correct.

I want to handle a holiday (as provided in dataframe) in the above code. So for example, if `dt_in` falls on any holiday (including `bd_3` and the `dt_tue`), then the bd_3 should be 14th Nov. Except that Holiday falls on Saturday or Sunday then bd_3 should be 15th Nov only.

Can any body please throw some light? Assume holiday Dataframe looks like below:

```
    Date                 Holiday_name           Day
January 1, 2019         New Year's Day        Tuesday
January 21, 2019      Martin Luther King Day  Monday
February 18, 2019     Presidents' Day*        Monday
May 27, 2019             Memorial Day         Monday
```

Comment: Isn't 3 business days before a Tuesday a Thursday?

Comment: No including Tuesday it is Friday.

Comment: Have you tried this with the starting day being a Thursday or Friday? I believe you'll find that those come out to a Monday or Tuesday, respectively, which doesn't match that logic

Comment: Ok gotcha. Then I need to fix this. Glad if you can help me in including the holiday.

Comment: I think if I set bd_3 as `dt - timedelta(days=2)` this issue is addressed. However, for Saturday and Sunday this should be `timedelta(days=4)` as mentioned in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're busy looping over all the days anyway, I suggest just doing a simple back-up and check each day as you go, something like:

```py
dt_tue = datetime.strptime('2019-11-19','%Y-%m-%d')
current_day = dt_tue
days_before = 0
while days_before < 2:
    # Skip weekends and holiday (without counting as a business day)
    while current_day.weekday() >= 5 or current_day in df['Date']:
        current_day -= timedelta(days=1)
    # Step back a business day
    current_day -= timedelta(days=1)
    days_before += 1
bd_3 = current_day
```

You may need to tweak that a bit as I'm not 100% sure how your holidays dataframe is formatted.

Comment: Please check for the date `2019-10-14` . This was Monday and a US holiday. Based on your logic the `bd_3` comes as `datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 11, 0, 0)` i.e. 11th Oct which was Friday. Which is not correct.

Comment: OK, I've fixed the weekday condition (it should be `>= 5`, not `> 5`), but since I don't know how your dataframe is formatted, the condition checking it is probably wrong. Hence my comment about you needing to tweak it accordingly

Comment: If you show how the dataframe is actually formatted that would help a lot

Comment: @Ixop: I have updated the question with holiday dataframe.

Comment: I don't have `pandas` installed here to verify my code, but I've updated the condition to what I think should work. You should be able to figure out the rest on your own